# Why do I get a back-ground thread 'Invoke' warning when I install a NuGet package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-console

This happens at least once a day, without visibly interfering with any other aspect of the packages facet of this project. When I enter an `install-package` command, this is the package manager's response in the console:

```
PM> Install-Package UmbracoCms
Invoke must be called on a background thread.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/umbracocms/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/umbracocms/index.json 306ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/umbracocms/page/7.6.0/7.6.3.json
```

All else seems to work fine, most of the time, after that. I have a fair suspicion that the installation of the dotnet and nuget CLIs may have played a role.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is currently under investigation:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/65296/invoke-must-be-called-on-a-background-thread.html

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5348